# How to write .gitlab-ci.yml job to run only in merge-request

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

How to right write job in .gitlab-ci.yml when it run only in  merge requests?

```
test_c:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something. It will only run when all jobs in the"
    - echo "build stage are complete."
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

This job not run in merge request, but not run and in commint in master or develop.

Answer (score 35):

Gitlab documentation recommends using 'rules' instead of 'only'. You can accomplish only merge_requests by doing the following:

```yml
test_c:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something. It will only run when all jobs in the"
    - echo "build stage are complete."
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowrules

Comment: Thanks, I was having issues using "if rules" and "only" at the same time.

Comment: Worth noting: this declaration is compatible with the situation when prior stages used `only: [merge_requests]` rather than the `if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"` as here *(not gonna rewrite those unless required as `only`-syntax is more readable. After all, gitlab didn't deprecate `only`)*.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `workflow` to control pipeline creation. Define this keyword at the top level, with a single `rules`. This example shows that the pipeline will only be executed when a new merge request is created, the last `when` is set to `never` to prevent pipelines from executing when a new branch is pushed to the server or for any other type of event.

```
workflow:
   rules:
     - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
       when: always
     - when: never
```

**Notice**
As mentioned in the Gitlab [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html)

> These pipelines are labeled as detached in the UI, and they do not have access to protected variables. Otherwise, these pipelines are the same as other pipelines.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is just not to run the job on specific branches, like **master** or **dev**, you may simply exclude them with `except`:

```
test_c:
  (...)
  except:
    - master
    - dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, commit it to master before test your merge_request pipelines please.